# Using tmpfs in Nextflow process (null value for variable with path)

Tags: docker, nextflow, tmpfs

I need some help with a situation. I want to try the `tmpfs` in order to speed up my process because the actual one is taking so long time (probably due to IO in python script).

So I defined the `containerOptions`

```
process my_app {

    tag "$_id"
    publishDir "${outdir}/my_app", mode: params.publish_dir_mode

    containerOptions "--tmpfs ${BLASTDB}:rw"

    input:
        val param1
        path file1
        path blast_db
        env BLASTDB
        ...
```

the value of `blast_db` is a S3 URI defined in nextflow.config `blast_db = "s3://${params.root_asset_bucket}/my_app/genome/BLASTDB_GRCH38`"

Then it is retrieved in the workflow as a file (to stage the path and the resources) and also as a string for the env variable `BLASTDB` (that will be read later on by the python script):

```
workflow my_app_wf {
    take:
        param1
        file1

    main:
        my_app (
            param1=param1,
            file1="${file1}",
            blast_db=file("${params.quest_haystack_pincushion_app.blast_db}"),
            BLASTDB=blast_db.getFileName().toString(),
            ...
        )
```

This is not working and the process fails due to:

```
Error executing process > 'my_app_wf:my_app (null)'
Caused by:
  Found a malformed value 'null:rw' for --tmpfs option
```

I tried multiple options like:

```
containerOptions "--tmpfs ${BLASTDB}"
containerOptions "--tmpfs ${BLASTDB}:rw"
containerOptions "--tmpfs ${blast_db}"
containerOptions "--tmpfs ${blast_db}:rw"
```

but always get the same error. What I am missing?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

containerOptions is a [process directive](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#directives), and process directives do not have access to channel values. If you make `BLASTDB` a global variable (maybe a param.BLASTDB in your config?) like you did with `outdir` both your `script`  block and your process directives will be able to access it.